# Updating GridView with a DropDownList control

Tags: c#, gridview, .net-3.5, asp.net-3.5

I have the following line in my code:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@priority", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Controls[0]).SelectedValue;
```

But when I run this, I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList'.
```

Any idea why this might be?

---

Relevant part of the GridView would be this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("priority") %>'></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("priority") %>'>
            <asp:ListItem Value="0">Low</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Normal</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="2">High</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Can you show us the aspx markup of the grid?

Comment: Use `FindControl("DropdownID")` method.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, updated question the relevant part of GridView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `DropDownList` most likely is in a `TemplateField` you can get it's reference via `FindControl("ID")`:

```
public void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
    GridViewRow row = gv.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    // assuming its ID is "DropDownList1"
    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("DropDownList1"); 
    String selectedValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use `e.Item.FindControl` in RowDataBound

```
var ddl = (DropDownList) e.Item.FindControl("YourId");
var value = ddl.SelectedValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
public void gv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    string spacediv3 = ((DropDownList)gridviewname.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[location].FindControl("dropdownlit1")).SelectedItem.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This is another method but this is not the recomended one.